# how to divide string before and after '-'

Tags: c#, .net, string

HI I have the following string in a textbox, I want to divide the each row and copy it in a excel cell.

```
61663254
61663236-61663250
61663254-61663280
61663254
61663254-61663280
```

if the line has '-' it should copy digit before '-' in the first cell 
the digits after '-' should be in the next cell.

if line has nnot any'-' it should copy digit in the line to both of the cells

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split the string:

```
foreach(var line in lines)
{
     string[] cells = line.Split('-');
     if (cells.Length == 1)
         cells = new string[] {cells[0], cells[0]};

     // Copy each cell into excel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split on line break or space and also on hyphen.

This code swaps all spaces for hyphens, then splits on hyphen.

```
string original = "61663254 61663236-61663250 61663254-61663280 61663254 61663254-61663280";
List<string> cells = original.Replace(" ", "-").Split('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `StringReader` and `string.Split` method, i.e.:

```
var s = 
@"61663254
61663236-61663250
61663254-61663280
61663254
61663254-61663280";

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(s))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var cells = line.Split('-');      

        if (cells.Length == 1)
        {
            cells = new[] { cells[0], cells[0] };
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```